# Group specific array elements together C

Tags: c, arrays

Say, you have an array,

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

Is it possible to output the display as such:

```
[0 6 12, 1 7 13, 2 8 14, 3 9 15, 4 10 16]
```

Such that each new array element consists of 3 previous array elements in that pattern, where every 6th element is not included.

so far all I can think of is, creating a temporary array, looping over the array elements and copying the respected element across, but I have no idea how to approach that.  Sorry I'm having difficulty providing example code, as the whole concept confuses me.

```
int i,j,adder = 0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){ //loop over 5 times for new array of size 5
    adder += 1;
    for(j=i+(i*5);j<i+(5*adder);j++){ //changing between elements and not including 6th value
    //stuck here
    }
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you want your output to be `[[ 0, 6, 12 ], [ 1, 7, 13 ], [ 2, 8, 14 ], [ 3, 9, 15 ], [4, 10, 16 ]]`? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Why are you printing with `%c` instead of `%d`?

Comment: @JonathanLam Yes that's the idea.  Sorry I should've been more careful how I formatted it.

Comment: Dou need an output like described or do you need a new data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea to use nested loops, but the inner loop needs to increment by `6` every time.

```
printf("[");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("[");
    for (j = i; j < 17; j += 6) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("]%s", (i < 4 ? ", " : ""));
}
printf("]");
```